# Rename multiple datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, rename

I have almost 400 dataframes loaded in R. But the names still have the .csv extension.

I read the data with this code

```
Files <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")

for (i in 1:length(Files)){
  assign(Files[i], 
         read.csv(Files[i], 
                  sep = ";", 
                  header = T))
}
```

Is there a way to remove the .cvs extension while importing the datasets?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not an answer, but please do not do this. Store your dataframes in a list instead of as 400 separate objects in the global namespace. You can use string manipulation to remove the names if you need to later, but don't do what you're doing here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that doesn't use `assign`, which is likely much better practice. You can keep the file names as the element names of the list.

```
library(tidyverse)
files <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")

df_list <- map(files, read_csv2)
names(df_list) <- str_remove(files, "\\.csv$")
```

Comment: Please can you explain why the above is better practice than using assign?

Comment: `assign` will place the dataframes into the global environment, which is easily modified by other parts of the code and may overwrite existing objects. You also can't iterate over the dataframes as easily. When you have some structure to your objects, put them into a data structure

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Files <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")
for (i in 1:length(Files)){
  assign(gsub("\\..*","",Files)[i], # replace your this line of code
         read.csv(Files[i], 
                  sep = ";", 
                  header = T))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add an extra `gsub` step:

```
Files <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")
File.name <- gsub("\\.csv$", "", Files)
for (i in 1:length(Files)){
  assign(File.name[i], 
         read.csv(Files[i], 
                  sep = ";", 
                  header = T))
}
```